# What does 'measure' mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> John McCormack included a popular balance in his repertoire, and was by every measure a superstar in his own right.

In the sentence above:

- What does "every measure a superstar" mean?
- What is the subject of *was*?
- What does *measure* mean in that sentence?
- And what part of speech is  *measure*?

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence measure just means a manner of judgement.

When one says "he is good by every measure", it means that he is good by ever single method you could possibly use to judge how he is good. So, "by every possible measure" in a lot of cases serves the same purpose as a modifier.

Answer (score -2):

Does it mean something like:

Whichever way you look at it, or in every respect he was a superstar in his own right.

?

The subject of "was" is John McCormack, and "measure" is a noun here I would say.

Comment: In fact it does, but an answer here should be definite not questioning.